# Accessing an object in JavaScript: Why do I need to use square bracket syntax instead of dot syntax in that case?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
var map = {
    Monday: [
        'something',
        'something else',
    ],
};
```

When trying to access it, I noticed something strange I don't understand:

Doing `console.log(map.Monday);` returns `undefined`. To get the array back, I need to do `console.log(map["Monday"]);`.

Why is this? I already tinkered with quotes and uppercase/lowercase identifiers. The only time I encountered this so far was when there were numbers involved in the identifier (but of course it was still a string).

**Edit**

According to the comments it's working – indeed that is correct. Then the reason is probably related to the fact that the array identifier comes from an HTML select element:

```
$('.select').on('change', function(event) {
    var selectedDay = $(event.currentTarget).val();

    if (map.hasOwnProperty(selectedDay)) {
        console.log(map[selectedDay]);
    }

});
```

Comment: in chrome it is working

Comment: `console.log(map.Monday);` returned `["something", "something else"]`, tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Your [code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/z1opbc59/) seems to be working for me...

Comment: Works in FF like posted. Both variants.

Comment: There's a closing single quote `'` is missing. This might be the problem

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Nope. Copied out from here and works w/o changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then the reason is probably related to the fact that the array identifier comes from an HTML select element.

Yes… the syntax `someObj.property` is equivalent to `someObj['property']`, i.e. the property name is passed as a string in square brackets there.

Now if you want to dynamically access some property, and only have the property name as a string, then you need to use the square bracket syntax. For example:

```
var day = 'Monday';
console.log(map[day]);
```

The `map[day]` is equivalent to `map['Monday']` which is equivalent to `map.Monday`. But if you were to call `map.day`, you would try to access `map['day']`, i.e. a property `day` in your object which obviously doesn’t exist.

---

What do we learn from this question? It’s a good idea to simplify the code in order to focus on the problem instead of including lots of irrelevant things. But when you do, you should make sure that the problem actually exists in the simpler code example. Because in this case, you eliminated the problem because you thought it doesn’t matter that you are trying to access the property dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript both objects and arrays can be accessed as arrays and also as objects:

```
var a = []; //array
a["x"] = 100; //works
a.y = 50; //works
a.z = a.x + a["y"]; //works

var b = {}; //object
b.x = 10; //works
b["y"] = 20; //works
b["z"] = b["x"] + b.y; //works
```

If you still have a problem it's not related to the code you posted.